Typescript актуален ли ещё namespace?
Всем привет. Как понял namespace в Typescript устаревшее и им только пользуются в старых проектах и использовался  ещё до стандарта ES6, где введены были import/export. Сейчас же все используют только import/export. Все верно? Я запутался немного

почему ты думаешь, что namespace устаревшее?

Вот хорошая статья на этот счет:
https://purpleschool.ru/knowledge-base/article/namespaces Все зависит от задачи использования.
Плюс ссылка на документацию:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html
